# Set android-gradle packagingOptions in the new experimental plugin

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

What is the equivalent to the andriod.packagingOptions in the android gradle experimental plugin?

In the current "stable" version it works as follows:

```
android{
 packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
 }
}
```

I tried mapping it inside the new android block but it didn't work. Also haven't found anything related to it on the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, you just have to declare it on the `android` configuration instead of making it inside the `android` block.

```
model {
    // ...
    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! But why isn't it the same as putting the packagingOptions tag inside the android scope? It's a bit counter intuitive

Comment: Agreed it's not intuitive at all. I think it has something to do with the way the new `model` api works in gradle.  The `model` api and this plugin are both not finalized so the requirement may change to be make more sense as the two evolve and the APIs are finalized.

Comment: Yeah, since it's experimental it can be understood. But how did you know it? Is there any documentation I am missing?